# How to undo changes in a closed tab VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I was trying to code and somehow I had sticky keys on and I ended up deleting all of my code and then on top of that I closed the tab so now i'm having a heart attack because all of my code which took 5 months, took just 1 second to lose.

Comment: Do you have source control like git? Do you have automatic backup/sync?

Comment: You really should have some sort of source control. It's like keeping your thesis paper open for months, never saving, then having Word crash.